# Creating multiple dataframes from a dictionary in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary like the below

```
d = {'a':'1,2,3','b':'3,4,5,6'}
```

I want to create dataframes from it in a loop, such as

```
a = 1,2,3
b = 3,4,5,6
```

Creating a single dataframe that can reference dictionary keys such as `df['a']` does not work for what I am trying to achieve. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get a list of dataframes:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dfs = [pd.DataFrame(np.array(b.split(',')), columns=list(a)) for a,b in d.items()]
```

gives the following output

```
>>> dfs[0]
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
>>> dfs[1]
   b
0  3
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Getting this error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. I should have specified that I have a nested dictionary, I assume that's where the issue is coming from.

Comment: are you using same value `d = {'a':'1,2,3','b':'3,4,5,6'}` ?

Answer (score 0):

To convert your dictionary into a **list of DataFrames**, run:

```
lst = [ pd.Series(v.split(','), name=k).to_frame()
    for k, v in d.items() ]
```

Then, for your sample data, `lst[0]` contains:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

and `lst[1]`:

```
   b
0  3
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Getting this error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. I should have specified that I have a nested dictionary, I assume that's where the issue is coming from.

Comment: The fact that you have **nested** dictionary changes a lot. My answer was prepared with "simple" dictionaries in mind. The mutation of your original task is actually a good material for **another** question, not for extending your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
dfs=[]  
for key, value in d.items():  
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict((list(filter(None, value)))) 
    dfs.append(df)
```