# Creating dfs from a nested dictionary and counting strings to create a plot with subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib

I have a df that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'job_title':['Senior Data Scientist', 'Junior Data Analyst', 'Data Engineer Intern', 'Data Engieneer/Architect', 'Data Analyst/Visualisation'],
    'location':['Berlin', 'Frankfurt', 'Munich','Frankfurt', 'Munich'],
    'job_desc':['something something Python, R, Tableau something', 'something R and SQL',
                 'something Power Bi, Excel and Python','something Power Bi, Excel and Python somthing', 'Power BI and R something']})
```

My objective is to now plot the necessary skills that appear in the job description  in `job_desc` column depending on the job title in `job_title`. Whats important is that the job titles in 'job_title' need to somehow filtered according to the three roles I mention below.

My idea was to do the following:

1. create sub data frames according to the job title for `Data Scientist`, `Data Analyst` and `Data Engineer`
2. creating new dfs from the ones I created that count the skills in the `job_desc`
3. plot the skills in a bar plot with three sub bar plot according to the role

To do this I have done the following:

1.)

```
# creating sub datasets according to the three roles above to look further into the different skillset

# data analyst dataset
dfa = df[df['job_title'].str.contains('Data Ana')]

# data scientist dataset
dfs = df[df['job_title'].str.contains('Data Sci')]

# data engineer dataset
dfe = df[df['job_title'].str.contains('Data Eng')]
```

2.) Here I created a loop and stored the obtained information in a nested dictionary. At first I tried to directly store the data from the loop in new data frames, but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502779/how-to-create-a-new-dataframe-with-every-iteration-of-for-loop-in-python) that it is best to do so using dictionaries.

```
# looping through each sub dataset to get the skill count
list = [dfa, dfs, dfe]

#creating an empty dictionary to store the new information in
dict_of_df = {}

for li in range(len(list)):

    # counting the skills in each df of the list
    python = list[li].job_desc.str.count('Python').sum()     
    R = list[li].job_desc.str.count('R ').sum()         
    tableau = list[li].job_desc.str.count('Tableau').sum()     
    pbi = list[li].job_desc.str.count('Power BI').sum()  
    excel = list[li].job_desc.str.count('Excel').sum()   
    sql = list[li].job_desc.str.count('SQL').sum()
    
    #creating a dictionary with the skills and their counts
    skills = ['python', 'R', 'pbi', 'tableau', 'excel', 'sql']
    counts = [python, R, tableau, pbi, excel, sql]
    dic = {'Skills': skills, 'Counts': counts}
        
    #appending the information in the empty dictionary
    dict_of_df['df_{}'.format(li)] = dic
```

This results in the following output:

```
dict_of_df = {{'df_0': {'Skills': ['python', 'R', 'pbi', 'tableau', 'excel', 'sql'], 'Counts': [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1]}, 'df_1': {'Skills': ['python', 'R', 'pbi', 'tableau', 'excel', 'sql'], 'Counts': [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, 'df_2': {'Skills': ['python', 'R', 'pbi', 'tableau', 'excel', 'sql'], 'Counts': [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]}}}
```

The dictionary contains the correct information and my desired output would then be to have three dfs from  `df_0`,`df_1` and `df_2` in this format:

```
Skills  Counts
0   python  0
1   R   1
2   pbi 0
3   tableau 0
4   excel   0
5   sql 1
```

But this I am not able to do, I tried to apply what I have found in these posts

[Creating multiple dataframes from a dictionary in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039733/creating-multiple-dataframes-from-a-dictionary-in-a-loop)

[Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)

[Construct a pandas DataFrame from items in a nested dictionary with lists as inner values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70049097/construct-a-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-a-nested-dictionary-with-lists-as-inn)

[Python Pandas: Convert nested dictionary to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460234/python-pandas-convert-nested-dictionary-to-dataframe)

However, all of the above posts have different dictionary structures as mine seems to be double nested. I also have the impression that my way may be too over complicating things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things, here is the simplified approach:

```
skills = ['python', 'R', 'pbi', 'tableau', 'excel', 'sql']
pattern = r'(?i)\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(skills)

s = df.set_index('job_title')['job_desc'].str.extractall(pattern)[0].droplevel(1) # -- step 1
s = pd.crosstab(s.index, s, rownames=['job_title'], colnames=['skills']) # -- step 2
```

##### Explained

Build a regex pattern using the `skills` then use `extractall` to find all the matching occurrences from each row of the job description column

```
# -- step 1

job_title
Senior Data Scientist     Python
Senior Data Scientist          R
Senior Data Scientist    Tableau
Junior Data Analyst            R
Junior Data Analyst          SQL
Data Engineer Intern       Excel
Data Engineer Intern      Python
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Create a frequency table using `crosstab`

```
# -- step 2

skills                 Excel  Python  R  SQL  Tableau
job_title                                            
Data Engineer Intern       1       1  0    0        0
Junior Data Analyst        0       0  1    1        0
Senior Data Scientist      0       1  1    0        1
```

That's it...Now depending upon how you would want to visualize the above data you can either use barplot or heat map. Personally I would prefer heatmap

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(s, cmap='Blues')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Shubam Sharma. Unfortunately, your code does not work for my df as the ``job_titles`` are all fairly different. I updated my df here in the question to make it clearer. 

To use your code I first need to replace the strings in the ``job_title`` column to either ``Data Scientist``,  ``Data Analyst`` or ``Data Engineer``.  So far I tried the following:
``df1 = df[np.logical_or(df_c['job_title'].str.contains('Data Ana'), df['job_title'].str.contains('Data Sci'), df['job_title'].str.contains('Data Eng'))]``, but this did not work.

Comment: So I now used: ```df.job_title = df.job_title.apply(lambda x: 'Data Analyst' if 'Data Ana' in x else x)
df.job_title = df.job_title.apply(lambda x: 'Data Scientist' if 'Data Sci' in x else x)
df.job_title = df.job_title.apply(lambda x: 'Data Engineer' if 'Data En' in x else x)``` and then your code and got the output I wanted! Thanks again. Could you just explain what this ``r'(?i)\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(skills)`` in the pattern expressions means and does and the step one part of you code in more detail please?